# How can I import images and assign them different names with a defined function in Pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm currently trying to create a cards against humanity game in Python using Pygame and I have created .jpg files for all the cards that I am now trying to import. I would like to create a function to import the pictures that I can then loop to quickly import all the picture, but I haven't found a way to make that work. In my mind, it would go sort of like this:

```
def img_import(name, filename):
    name = pygame.image.load(filename)
```

but I know that this won't work and I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Why even use a function here? `someName = pygame.image.load(filename)` works fine. If you really wanted a function though, you could have your `img_import` function `return` the result of `load`, then do `someName = img_import(filename)`. Just don't try to assign within the function.

Comment: Oh it is simply because I am importing over 600 images...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a number of ways that this task could be done. the simplest and possibly best way would be to maintain a dictionary with the name and the surface of said image.
this could be implemented as so

```
def img_import(name, filename):
    cards[name] = pygame.image.load(filename)

file_names = [] # fill this list with the names of all of the files
names = [] # fill with the card names
cards = {}
for card in range(file_names):
    img_import(names[card], file_names[card]
```

this will create a dictionary to map from each name to a image surface

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary:

```
images = {}
def img_import(name, filename):
    images[name] = pygame.image.load(filename)
```

You could also use a list and somewhere write which index refers to which image:

```
images = []
index = 0
names = {}
def img_import(name, filename):
    global index
    images.append(pygame.image.load(filename))
    names[name] = index
    index += 1
```

**Best way (IMHO) below**

But if you want all the names and make it also more readable it's easier to copy/paste

> = pygame.image.load(filename)

for every name.